# Make UIView Height Dependent On Negative Space Between Two Objects

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiview, interface-builder

I know how to do this in code, but I am desperately trying to get this to work via the interface builder.

I have a UIView's, and then 2 UIView's below it.

I have the top UIView and the Bottom UIView set with rigid constraints.

I want the middle UIView to resize based on the space between them. If you look at the image below you can see the white space. I would like to know what constraint(s) I could use so that the dark blue bar bases its height on the space between the upper and lower UIViews.

**TL;DR** How can I get the dark blue bar to have its height be the negative space between 2 views.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just set top and bottom constraints to 0? Ie white-0-darkblue-0-lightblue.

Comment: I tried that and it seems to be not working. Perhaps I need to take a second pass

Comment: It ended up being priorities. When I changed the priority of the dark blue bar to low, it removed all the red lines and fit the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dark blue bar should have the following constraints:

- vertical space to white view = 0
- vertical space to light blue view = 0
- leading space to superview = 0
- trailing space to superview = 0